# How to make procedural world creation like Breakneck in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, procedural

I want to make a game like breakneck with unity 
I am a intermediate developer with unity3d 
One thing that I stuck with is world creation like this game somebody explain and help me creating this .
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This links might help you.

Best Unity Procedural Generation Tutorials

1. Catlike Coding - Procedrual Levels: http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/
2. AlexStv - Voxel Terrain : http://alexstv.com/index.php/category/voxels
3. ScrawkBlog - Procedural Terrain/Noise + GPU : http://scrawkblog.com/

And there's also a procedural example in unity asset store and here is the link: 
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/5141

Here's the best resources :

1. Rouglike Procedural Games : http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Main_Page
2. Procedural Dungeon Techniques : http://www.futuredatalab.com/proceduraldungeon/

Source from here : https://forum.unity.com/threads/best-unity-procedural-generation-tutorials.294890/